# I need to remember my canvas drawing on page refresh

Tags: javascript, canvas, drawing, page-refresh

I have a script that uploads files, input fields and a canvas drawing all in a folder. It works except that when I uploaded my canvas, it would upload it before the folder was created thuss putting it in nothing. I have fixed that by saying that it needs to upload after the form and all images are submitted.. however this causes the page to refresh and thuss resetting my canvas drawing (to a blank canvas). I need a way to remember my canvas drawing on page refresh. Here is my code:

```
<?php if ($savescript == 1) { ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var myDrawing = document.getElementById("simple_sketch");
        var drawingString = myDrawing.toDataURL("image/jpg");
        var postData = "canvasData="+drawingString;
        var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
        ajax.open("POST",'saveimage.php',true);
        ajax.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'canvas/upload');
        ajax.onreadystatechange=function()
            {
                if (ajax.readyState == 4)
                {alert("image saved");}
            }
            ajax.send(postData);
    });
</script>
<?php }; ?>
```

$savescript is based on a hidden input field that has the value of 1, so it'll only send after the form is submitted

** Insert standard HTML page code here **

Then here is my canvas wich is inside a form

```
<canvas id="simple_sketch" name="simple_sketch" width="800" height="300"></canvas>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(function() {
        $('#simple_sketch').sketch();
      });
    </script>
```

So how can I let the canvas remember what was drawn before the page reload?

NEED HALP :p

Comment: Why is this question tagged in php

Comment: You could save it as an image, then draw that image in your canvas when the page is reloaded.

Comment: Sorry, I have php too but it's not relevant for the question. I'll try to remove the tag

Comment: @KoenHoeijmakers That could work very good! I'll give it a try thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Does the page need to refresh? If you're already making ajax calls it might be easier to use    `preventDefault` to stop the refresh and let the rest of the code execute. You will then be able to keep the reference to your canvas object.

Comment: When using preventDefault the page won't reload wich is great, but it also doesn't submit the images, input fields or creates the directory.. so I guess this isn't an option for me.

Comment: @brancoholtslag Is it due to the `$savescript` hidden field? You may need to programmatically set that, or perhaps remove it if it is no longer required?

Comment: No it prevents the other images from uploading, it just keeps loading and loading but never uploads them to the actual server so it basically won't even let me get to the part where the canvas is uploaded.

Comment: I'm assuming (and we all know what that does) that the page the canvas is drawn on is separate to the page that receives the POST request.I'd also suggest the `$(document).ready()` code be moved into to an event handler on the submit button. e.g., `$('#submitButton').click(function(){...});`